Best practices on React for rendering lists
I'm just learning react and I saw so far 2 ways of rendering lists, the first declaring a const after mapping the data and then rendering this new list and the second one mapping directly inside the jsx

Which way would be more appropiate, is used normally?

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

Both are practically the same. You\ll use the first one if you want to to something like !cards.length to show some other context. (Not really in your example since you're already checking !cardsData, but the idea stays the same.

They are the same, but 1 is better, removing the code complexity from the jsx.

Thats an opinion @gaitat, any way of showing 'why its better'

I agree with zmo, that the 2nd option is better. Keeping the stuff you are going to render together improves readability and cognitive load.
But there is a 3rd option; creating an intermediary component i.e <CardContainer> that renders a list of cards. This way the <App> is off the hook when is comes to rendering the <Card> components.
Also, when you use map, don't forget to assign a unique key to your items!


const { useState, StrictMode } = React;

const App = ({ title }) => {
  const cardsData = CardsData();
  return <CardContainer cards={cardsData} />
};

const CardContainer = ({ cards }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      {cards && cards.length
        ? cards.map((card) => <Card key={card.id} {...card} />)
        : "No cards..."}
    </div>
  );
};

const Card = ({ id, name, img, rarity }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card" data-rarity={rarity}>
      <div className="card-name">{name}</div>
      <div className="card-image">
        <img src={img} />
      </div>
      <div className="card-text">Flavor text here...</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <StrictMode>
      <App/>
    </StrictMode>
  );

function CardsData() {
  return [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mighty Cat', img: 'https://placecats.com/bella/120/120', rarity: 'EPIC' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Strong Cat', img: 'https://placecats.com/bella/120/120', rarity: 'RARE' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Cat', img: 'https://placecats.com/bella/120/120', rarity: 'COMMON' }
  ];
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card[data-rarity="EPIC"] { background: purple; }
.card[data-rarity="RARE"] { background: blue; }
.card[data-rarity="COMMON"] { background: yellow; }

.card[data-rarity="EPIC"],
.card[data-rarity="RARE"] {
  .card-name {
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
  }
}

/* Holographic hover effect */
.card[data-rarity="EPIC"] {
  .card-image {
    position: relative;
    
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3),
        rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.3),
        rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3),
        rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3),
        rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3),
        rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3),
        rgba(139, 0, 255, 0.3)
      );
      mix-blend-mode: overlay;
      opacity: 0.6;
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    &:hover {
      img {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg) brightness(1.5);
      }
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      filter: hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(1.2) contrast(1.1);
      mix-blend-mode: screen;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
  }
}

.card {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 12rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  color: black;
}

.card-name {
  border: thin solid black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.card-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card-text {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  font-size: smaller;
}
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




Thanks for the code, between the ternary in cardcontainer, the use of ...card for attributes and the holo cat, I buy your 3rd option :D

We're bordeline on style/opinion here, but my take on this is that:
option #2 is better when it's really as simple as what you wrote (directly mapping a list of instances into a list of components without logic in between). And it does it all in one place, so readability is best.
I don't think #1 is a good option for two reasons: the JSX stuff should be (as much as possible) in the render part (i.e. the return) not before the render. Above the render, we manipulate the data, after we build the DOM. And also it makes you look at two places for something trivial that should be done all at once.
And if you ever need to make the map lambda more complex than a direct one liner, then don't. Either transform the data before the render, or do it in the <Card /> component.
N.B.: I'm giving the opposite answer from @gaitat, but with a rationale: [before return it's data, after it's JSX]. And I agree with the principle, it's just that I consider a .map() not being code complexity.
